# Edittext Can not be editable due to property descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in My Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I am facing some problem my edittext is not editable due to descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in Recyclerview.There is one Activity that have Recyclerview. if i am not use this descendantFocusability then my list loses its focus. Can anybody help me to solve this issue????? How to make Edittext editable. i was tried all solution like focusableintouchmode="true" and focusabale="false" etc.

Thanks in Advance.

```
**MyActivity.class**

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:andandroid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

**raw.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:hedgehog="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rawSubQuestion"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_black_left_right"
android:minHeight="@dimen/_70sdp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_35sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp">

    <!--Name-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        style="@style/commonTextStyle"
        android:text="Name" />

    <!--Description-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        style="@style/commonTextStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="@style/RatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/circleRatingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <com.whinc.widget.ratingbar.RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBarCircle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:rb_click_rating="true"
                app:rb_count="3"
                app:rb_empty="@drawable/r_circle_white"
                app:rb_fill="@drawable/r_circle_yellow"
                app:rb_max_count="10"
                app:rb_space="10dp"
                app:rb_touch_rating="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CircleRatingTV"
                style="@style/commonTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="1" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:max="10"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:progress="5"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_drawable"
                android:thumbOffset="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSeekBarCount"
                style="@style/commonTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<!--Note-->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtNote"
    style="@style/editTextWhiteGray"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="@string/Note"
    android:layout_below="@id/rlMain"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Your Prb solve or not?

Comment: Not yet same issue ramining

Answer (score 1):

Your EditText is outside of your root ViewGroup (RelativeLayout):

```
</RelativeLayout>

<!--Note-->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtNote"
    style="@style/editTextWhiteGray"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="@string/Note"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

Include that EditText inside of your RelativeLayout. Also you should add ***android:inputType*** look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for more info. Add ***LayoutParams*** to all of your views where it's missing, why it is required described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params). And recheck all your logic concerning EditText widget in your code.

Comment: After Impliment Your suggestion EditText is not Displayed :(

Comment: Add android:inputType="text" into EditText, that should fix the issue and let me know

Comment: I am confused ) then you should edit your problem, people may think about this issue: **My EditText is not editable**!

Comment: When you requested a focus once by **holder.edtNote.requestFocus();** you should check in other places of your code if edtNote has a focus then remove it.

Comment: I was Change my Code ..Can you help me?

Comment: To fix issue with edittext focus I suggest you to do following: 1) create an instance variable, such as: **private boolean focused = false;** 2) edittext's requestFocus method returns boolean value, change your code to this: **focused = holder.edtNote.requestFocus();** and 3) at the beginning of your if...else logic add this: **if (focused) { holder.edtNote.clearFocus(); focused = false; }**

Comment: You shouldn't remove your code and comments. The focus issue may be in your code not in xml and comments would help to follow what was discussed earlier

Comment: I can't Understand in your 2nd Point Can you Please briefly Explain it??
 edittext's requestFocus method returns boolean value, change your code to this: focused = holder.edtNote.requestFocus();

Comment: in your code you are calling this method: holder.edtNote.requestFocus(); This method provides your edtNote with focus and returns boolean result. So, focused = holder.edtNote.requestFocus(); means set focus on edtNote and assign boolean result to the variable focused.

Comment: I can change My Adapter Code As you say.. see my code changes

Comment: did that fixed your issue with focus in EditText?

Comment: Still Confuse 
Where to Add this Line : focused = holder.edtNote.requestFocus();

Comment: nobody knows the problem domain better then you. Do you exactly need that focus on your EditText? If yes, when do you need it? What user has to do in order to get focus on EditText? If user are focused on EditText then what? For all of these questions you must answer by yourself.

Comment: Ok .. Thank you for Such a kind help :)